# Custom copying dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, copy

How can I copy dynamic array like that: Copy all elements of array, but start in second array not from 0 index, but from first.

```
//We have array x, which have 5 elements, and array y, which have 6 elements;
y[1]=x[0];
y[2]=x[1];
//etc...
```

P.S. Don't want copy element by element, can I use in that way `std::copy` or `memcpy` ??

EDIT: Is it more efficient way to reallocate an array than this?

```
int* arr = new int[20];
...
//wanna resize to 25?
int* temp = new int[25];
std::copy(arr, arr+20, temp);
delete [] arr;
arr = temp;
... //now arr has 25 elements
```

But without using vector or other stl objects.

Comment: Since we don't know what is *in* your arrays, its hard to say whether `std::copy`, `memcpy`, both, or *neither* is appropriate for your task. `std::copy` would *likely* work, but that assumes whatever type these are is at-least assignable.

Comment: it has `uint8_t` variables

Comment: ok, i have it, thanks a lot for help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::copy uses iterators, so you can increment the destination iterator by one:

for fixed size arrays and c++11, this should work:

```
std::copy( std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::begin(y)+1 )
```

for dynamic arrays, std::end does not work, but pointer arithmetics can be used:

```
std::copy( x, x+5, y+1 )
```

Comment: `std::begin` is from which library?

Comment: This is c++11. But you're right, this is not working for dynamic arrays. But you can use raw pointers instead. Someone like: std::copy( x, x+<length of x>, y+1) should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `std::copy` or any of the appropriate memory copy/move functions (`memcpy`, `memmove` if regions overlap) for your situation, the latter because your object type (`uint8_t`) is *trivially-copy-assignable*.

You should also know `std::copy` will *likely* do the latter *for you* if your type is trivially copy assignable (and `uint8_t` is so). This is *not* a requirement (at least none that I'm aware of, I'm sure I'll hear about it if it is) but each vendor I've seen provides a [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) solution for trivially-copy-assignable objects to simply perform a `memmove` in the interest of efficiency.

In short, you will likely get what you want with `std::copy`

```
std::copy(x, x+x_len, y+1);
```

and make sure `y` has at least `x_len+1` slots available.